# Cannot add authentication on app with connection string error

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am trying to add authentication to my application using the built in provider however I am getting an error doing so. My web.config file is as follows (with the db etc taken out of connection string but does all work):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LaundryDBContext"
         connectionString=".amazonaws.com,1433;
         Initial Catalog=Main;
         Persist Security Info=True;
         User ID=****;
         Password=****;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

When trying to add authentication I am getting the following error:

```
The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.
```

I would love the authentication and application settings to be stored in the existing DB. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectionStringName property of the provider entries are set to "ApplicationServices" which is not a named connection string in your web.config.  Your connection string is named "LaundryDBContext".

Change the connnectionStringName property to "LaundryDBContext" and the provider will use that connection string to talk to your database.

You should [read one](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/SqlMembershipProvider.aspx) of [the many walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29) on  [configuring membership](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/06/16/usage-of-aspnet-regsql-exe-in-asp-net-4.aspx) to understand how that works in more detail.

In brief...

1. open the visual studio command prompt and type `aspnet_regsql`
2. Follow the wizard in the dialog that opens to add the aspnet membership schema to your database.

Comment: I have now done so however I get the following error: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: this is because you have not run aspnet_regsql.exe against your database.  This tool will create the tables required to store the membership data.

Comment: I have also changed the inital catalog to recreate the database and get the following error: Cannot open database "New" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'dbuser'. Even though I know the connection details are correct for this user.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials as to how to do this?

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a dream!